# static variable not working in android broadcastreceiver

Tags: java, android, variables, static, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to use pressure sensor.

After every 6 sec read sensor value and show.
But it  always shows "0.0"

First time I tried static variable...but not working.
Now using singleton, still it is not working.

I don't know where I am wrong.

Help me. Please.

**/* broadcastReceiver */**

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int count = 0;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    SensorValue sv = SensorValue.getInstance();

    Toast.makeText(context, "Barometer : " + String.valueOf( sv.getBaroVal() ) +  " count : " + String.valueOf( count ), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); // For example
    count++;

    wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
}
```

**/* singleton */**

```
public class SensorValue {
private static SensorValue singleton = new SensorValue();
private double baroVal = 0.0;

private SensorValue(){
}

public static SensorValue getInstance(){
    return singleton;
}

public void setBaroVal( double val ) {
    baroVal = val;
}

public double getBaroVal() {
    return baroVal;
}
}
```

**/* MainActivity */**

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE:
        sv.setBaroVal( event.values[0] );
        break;
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: Krupa Patel Thank You ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change your SensorValue class to below.

```
          public class SensorValue {
          private static SensorValue singleton;
          private double baroVal = 0.0;

          private SensorValue(){
           singleton = new SensorValue();
          }

          public static SensorValue getInstance(){
           if(singleton == null)
           {
               singleton = new SensorValue();
           }

           return singleton 
       } 

       public void setBaroVal( double val ) {
           baroVal = val;
       }

       public double getBaroVal() {
         return baroVal;
      }
   }
```

I don,t know whether it will work or not though test it with once.

Comment: thank you for response. singleton working fine in other place. only problem in broadcastreceiver.onReceive

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a reason.

in manifest file. i set receiver option like this

`android:process=":remote"`

it worked another process.

have a good day.